# Save password prompt behavior inconsistent between browsers: Firefox, Chrome, Edge

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, passwords, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I have a simple html form that allows a signed-in user to update their password.  Originally, the form did not contain a username field.  Because it did not contain a username, when Firefox would prompt the user to save their new password, the prompt would have a blank username field:

[image]

To fix this, I added a username field like in the example code below, populated the value with the current signed-in username before rendering the page, and hid the input with css (`.visually-hidden` has `display:none;`).  This had the desired effect on Firefox and it now populates the username in the 'save password' prompt.

After this change, however, Chrome and Edge no longer prompt to save the user's password.  Before the change, Chrome and Edge had worked as desired, and even somehow populated the username field in the prompts.  After the change, no prompt shows to offer to save the changed password.

Does anyone have any ideas for what I should do to get the save password behavior working consistently between Firefox, Chrome, and Edge?  I've tried un-hiding the username input, adding/removing autocomplete attributes, removing the pre-populated username value from the input, making the input type="email", but nothing has worked so far on Chrome (I didn't verify each attempt on Edge).

Thank you.

```
    <form action="https://[example].com/password-confirm/" method="post" id="NewPasswordForm" name="NewPasswordForm" novalidate="novalidate">
  <fieldset>
    <input class="input-text visually-hidden" type="text" name="username" value="my_email@example.com" autocomplete="username email">

    <div class="form-row  required" aria-required="true">
      <label for="dwfrm_resetpassword_password"><span class="error-icon"></span><span>New Password</span><span class="required-indicator">*</span></label>
      <div class="field-wrapper">
        <input class="input-text password required" type="password" id="dwfrm_resetpassword_password" name="dwfrm_resetpassword_password" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="255" minlength="6" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
      </div>
      <div class="form-caption "></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row  required" aria-required="true">
      <label for="dwfrm_resetpassword_passwordconfirm"><span class="error-icon"></span><span>Verify Password</span><span class="required-indicator">*</span></label>
      <div class="field-wrapper">
        <input class="input-text password required" type="password" id="dwfrm_resetpassword_passwordconfirm" name="dwfrm_resetpassword_passwordconfirm" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="255" minlength="6" aria-required="true">
      </div>
      <div class="form-caption "></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row-button">
      <button type="submit" class="apply" name="dwfrm_resetpassword_send" value="Apply">Update Password</button>
      <a class="cancel" href="https://[example].com/preferences-summary/">Cancel</a>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say it worked on Edge and Chrome before the change and worked on Firefox after the change, so I think you can apply the change for Firefox alone.

You can first detect if the browser is Firefox in JavaScript, if so then add the visually-hidden `input`. Then the `input` will only be added in Firefox and won't affect Edge/Chrome:

```
<fieldset>
    <div id="invisible"></div>
    ...
</fieldset>
```

```
<script>
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
        // Do Firefox-related activities
        document.getElementById('invisible').innerHTML = '<input class="input-text visually-hidden" type="text" name="username" value="my_email@example.com" autocomplete="username email">';
    }
</script>
```

Result in Firefox and Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the response, but unfortunately I don't think I can use this solution.  It's too likely that a browser hack like this could cause issues in the future if Firefox updates to handle their password prompts consistently with Chrome and Edge.  I am hoping someone can point out some html standard that I missed in my form which I can fix directly to make it work consistently cross-browser.  If no one can spot something like that, I may end up needing to just leaving it as-is and hope that Mozilla gets their browser working consistently to the others.

Comment: The different behavior is due to different browser kernel. It's by design. Let's see if other community members have other ideas. Besides, I also suggest that you can provide your feedback to Firefox about the issue.